# Background DIV to be anchored to top of the browser

Tags: html, css, background

I hope I am able to explain this one okay, but I am working on a web site that has multiple (background) DIVS stacked upon each other each containing a background image. I have a button for each DIV which when clicked the browser scolls to bring that DIV into view... I hope this illustrates the situation better:

[image]

the background image resizes with the browser which works perfectly fine apart from one small issue... Unless I am on the TOP Div - When I change the height of the browser the background image starts slidding down the page, again, I hope this screenshot helps:

[image]

I want to be able to lock the current/active background to the top of the browser when re-sizing. Is this possible at all?

I am in work at the moment so unable to supply any of my existing code till later but I am hopeful someone out there might have had the same problem and easily fixed it?

*** EDIT ***

Here is my current code:

HTML For the 'buttons':

```
<div id="Container" class="sp-full">

<div>
    <a href="#divIntro"><div id="btnIntro"></div></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#divCode"><div id="btnCode"></div></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#divData"><div id="btnData"></div></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#divDesign"><div id="btnDesign"></div></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#divOrbit"><div id="btnOrbit"></div></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#divComingSoon"><div id="btnComingSoon"></div></a>
</div>
```

The backgrounds are held as follows (minus content):

```
<div class="divBackround divIntro">
</div>

<div id="divCode" class="divBackround">
</div>

<div id="divData" class="divBackround">
</div>

<div id="divDesign" class="divBackround">
</div>

<div id="divOrbit" class="divBackround">
</div>

<div id="divComingSoon" class="divBackround">
</div>
```

And the Javascript that makes the magic happen:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").on('click', function (event) {

        if (this.hash !== "") {

            event.preventDefault();

            var hash = this.hash;

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 50
            }, 800, function () {

                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you put {background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image?v=example) property to your `body` tag? Else what is the background you are talking about? Is it another container div that houses other divs shown above?

Comment: Why not make it position:fixed once the scrolling has completed - that way it will always stay in the same position

Comment: I'm guessing you use javascript since the browser "scrolls" to bring something in view. If this is the case, you set the browsers scroll position to a certain amount based on the viewport height. When you resize the browser, this viewport height changes, but the scroll position remains the same. This might cause your problem.

Comment: Hope this helps:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Comment: Thanks All - I have a lot to look at there, especially with the javascript controlling the scroll position! I will try a few ideas from this out later and update. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you need to keep track not of the scroll position itself, but the chosen element's relative position.

Then, when you resize, recalculate its correct top position value.

```js
(function(timeout) {
  var position;
  
  function keepposition() {
    window.scrollTo(0, window.innerHeight * position);
  }

  function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if (duration <= 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 20;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        if (element.scrollTop === to) return;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 20);
    }, 10);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      (function(i){
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
          position = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-pos'));
          scrollTo(document.body, window.innerHeight * position, 600);
        }, false);
      })(i);
    }
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener("resize", resized, false);
  function resized() {
    if ( !timeout ) {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = null;
        resizeHandler();
       }, 10);
    }
  }
  
  function resizeHandler() {
    keepposition();
  }    
}());
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.bkg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}
.bkg.nr1 {
  top: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
}
.bkg.nr2 {
  top: 200vh;
  background: green;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
}
button + button {
  left: 80px;
}
button + button + button {
  left: 160px;
}
```

```html
<button data-pos="0">First</button><button data-pos="1">Second</button><button data-pos="2">Third</button>

<div class="bkg nr0"></div>
<div class="bkg nr1"></div>
<div class="bkg nr2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks LGSon. This looks good but I am not sure this incorporates easily into what I already have (which I haven't yet put up). My 'buttons'are 'a' elements (HTML Hyperlinks) that are linked to some Javascript. When clicked it is initiated to smoothly scroll the page down to the next div. I will see if I can get the code on here to help visualize things a bit better.

Comment: I have just updated the post with an example of my code

Comment: Hi LGS, the little time I have had i have unsuccessfully tried to implement what you have kindly supplied above into the way I am already handling the scrolling. That being said, I would be interested to see if you were able to adapt your code so there is a smoother scroll between backgrounds instead of the button clicks just jumping straight to the next.

Comment: BTW - I have updated the original post with my code so you can see how I am currently working with this.

Comment: @CJH I will have a look soon. And it is always appreciated to get an upvote when one post an answer, especially when one being asked to elaborate even more :)

Comment: @CJH Updated my answer with a smoother scroll, hope it helps :) ... will be away for a few hours, but will check back later

Comment: Thanks again for the update here LGS! It is all very close - although the biggest problem is that (as you will see from my code above) my 'buttons' are exclusive of the background divs that are moving. I have all my buttons visible at all times whereas it looks like your example is reliant on the buttons being inside each respective background DIV. I have tried to use your example above but I just don't seem to be able to integrate with my current design.

Comment: @CJH Updated again...changed the logic and am now using an attribute set on the buttons, which tells the position of the div to go to. Now I can't make it simpler :)

Comment: Thanks again LGS - However your example is still relying on buttons being within the respective background DIVs. If you take a look at my screenshots particularly, you should make out a strip of icons in the middle-left of the screen. These are my buttons and remain in the same place wherever the scroll position. All buttons are always visible. You will see from my code snippets how these are setup within their own DIVs, exclusive of the DIVs containing the background.

Comment: @CJH No, buttons does not need to be within a div any more. Made one more update, where I positioned buttons on top, fixed.

Comment: Ahhhh sorry, I missed that in my rush. I am starting to get a bit more luck with this now so hopefully can mark this as the correct answer shortly! I really appreciate you patience and perseverance on this.

Comment: @CJH You're welcome .... and of course it is the correct answer, it is only you who need to understand it :)

Comment: Definitely - There are a few nice new techniques you have going on there that I will look forward to understanding it all fully.